# How to add more than one IdentityServer4 Authentication in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I added into my project IdentityServer4 and create my implementation of `IExtensionGrantValidator`. Also we have another project which can issue tokens which can be valid for our service.
[There is a scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cVlf.png).
How can I validate token in local Identity starage and External? Both of them were written by our teams.
If I add

```
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Reference;
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ApiName = "myApi";
                    options.ApiSecret = "userSecret";
                })
```

into my Startup.cs then token will be validate only in one service.

Answer (score 0):

In this case was very helpful [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0). I just add new IdentityServerAuthentication in my Startup with another scheme name. Example:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Reference;
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ApiName = "myApi";
                    options.ApiSecret = "mySecret";
                })
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("ExternalAuth",
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Reference;
                        options.Authority = appSettings.IdentityServiceExternal;
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        options.ApiName = "myApi";
                        options.ApiSecret = "mySecret";
                    }
                )
```

But it sends two requests: first for default scheme (in my case `"Bearer"` on `localhost:5000`), second one for additional scheme (`"ExteralAuth"`) even if response for default scheme was valid.